# Existem alguma diferença entre First e Single?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, terminologia, linq-to-entities

Existem alguma diferença entre First e Single?

o retorno das duas consultas são iguais?

E em questão de performance entre os dois é o mesmo?

Qual das duas expressões é melhor usar?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic, SingleOrDefault() e diferente de Single, apesar de não ter achado essa pergunta exatamente por ser diferente.  o mesmo vale para First.

Comment: Não é @Marconcilio Souza é a mesma coisa! só tem um incremento a mais que pode retornar um valor padrão! mas, é a mesma coisa! inclusive parte de exception é idênticas!

Comment: @VirgilioNovic, se fosse a mesma coisa, me fale para que desenvolveram dois métodos com a mesma função? com nomes diferentes?  deu a loka nos desenvolvedores da Microsoft ?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic, veja isso https://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=6&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjlwtyFrajQAhURl5AKHeLND2IQFghHMAU&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.dotnettricks.com%2Flearn%2Flinq%2Funderstanding-single-singleordefault-first-and-firstordefault&usg=AFQjCNFCRjUvHILyD9mzGwz7TjG54Gz3zA&bvm=bv.138493631,d.Y2I .....

Comment: Eles fazem a mesma coisa, a única diferença é que se não tiver nenhum erro eles vão retornar o valor ou um padrão.  O link não demonstrou nada! Desculpas ... !

Comment: Só lembrando que duplicata mais pessoas avaliam não é só eu!

Comment: @VirgilioNovic, fazer a mesma coisa e ter uma diferença são coisas distintas, sei que um só voto para fechar não é suficiente, mas seguiram seus passos depois que você sinalizou como duplicata.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48481/discussion-between-virgilio-novic-and-marconcilio-souza).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Single` irá lançar uma exceção se a consulta retornar mais de um registro. Espera-se somente um registro.

`First` não irá lançar exceção para esse caso, e irá retornar `TOP 1` do resultado. Espera-se 1 ou mais registros, mas retorna somente o primeiro.

Ambos lançam exceção quando nenhum registro é retornado.

Como você vê, são dois objetivos diferentes. Cabe você decidir qual usar para cada cenário.

Answer (score 0):

A sutil diferença entre `First` e `Single` é que este último impõe a regra de que a consulta à base de dados deve retornar apenas um registro. Para assegurar tal restrição, o método Single emite uma cláusula *SQL TOP 2*. Se dois registros forem retornados, ele emite uma exceção. Se zero registros forem retornados, ele emite uma exceção, a menos que você use `SingleOrDefault`, que tem o mesmo comportamento de `FirstOrDefault`.

O mais recomendado e o `First`, em vez de `Single`, por três razões;

1. Quando você souber que está recuperando um objeto, não haverá sentido emitir um `TOP 2` contra a base de dados;
2. `Single` é ligeiramente mais lento que `First`; e
3. Verificar apenas um registro para os parâmetros de entrada deve ser responsabilidade da fase de atualização da base de dados, e não da faze de  consulta.